# Is it legal to use real people in education material?

Tags: copyright, education

We are doing a game-like app on the topic of literature where we will portray some of the writers with illustrations and animations, also making them utter certain things. Would this require permission from those still living?

For example imagine in a game, you walk into a library and see a JK Rowling - you click on her and she "tells" you some facts about her, and her work.

Comment: JK Rowling is probably not the best example to use these days...

Comment: Whether the author is living or dead is going to be important.

Answer (score -1):

It's legal. Real, living people are used often in games and movies, so yeah, it's legal.

Comment: Examples, sources? Because all the Google searches pointed me to the fact that it is NOT legal. I'd like it to be though :)